# Subprocess "python file.py" – how to ensure runs in python3?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm running the following piece of code:

```
p = subprocess.getoutput("python ./file.py")
```

How do I ensure the python version used is python3?

Thanks!

Comment: you might want to change the code so that it runs on both: `p=subprocess.check_output('python ./file.py < input.txt', shell=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your controlling script is running in python 3, and thus you are simply wanting to run a subprocess of an identical version of python, then try:

```
import sys
p = subprocess.getoutput("'{}' ./file.py < input.txt".format(sys.executable))
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to ensure python 3.x is used is:

```
p = subprocess.getoutput("python3 ./file.py < input.txt")
```